# Couple Side Image banner follow based on responsive DOM

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd problem to make 2 images left and right move at proper position for my simple banner.

Here were my sample left and right Image:

[image]
[image]

I'd spent a lot of time for only this simple thing. Any helps much appreciated.

*My expected output:*

[image]

*The codes I've tried:*

```css
.content-up-comming-event
{
  font-size:0.85em;
  min-height:200px; 
  width:96%; 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  background-color:#ccc; 
  padding:20px 15px;
  z-index:100;
}
.img-left-curve
{
  margin-bottom: -115px; 
  max-width: 14px; 
  z-index:-1;
}
.banner-up-comming-event
{
  height:40px; 
  padding-top:8px; 
  color:#fff; 
  text-align: center; 
  background-color:#000; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ylry.png" class="img-left-curve" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-up-comming-event">Upcoming Event</div>
  <div class="content-up-comming-event">
    <p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; ">Events</span></strong><br/>DDD HQ, Street <br/> 22 Dec 2015</p>
    <p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; ">New EW Training (NET)</span></strong><br/>Street HQ, City <br/> 08 Jan 2016<br/>2pm - 6pm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do they have to be images? Just curious.

Comment: Not really. If all in css then that's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here it is. I used your image and flipped it for the right side. I also tryed small tricks to enahnce the 3d feeling you are trying to create with that header. I hopw you like it.

```css
.banner-up-comming-event:before,
.banner-up-comming-event:after {
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ylry.png) 0 50% no-repeat;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
  z-index: -1;
}
.banner-up-comming-event:before {
  left: 0;
}
.banner-up-comming-event:after {
  right: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
.banner-up-comming-event {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .27);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.content-up-comming-event {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 0 14px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .27);
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="banner-up-comming-event">Upcoming Event</div>
  <div class="content-up-comming-event">
    <p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; ">Events</span></strong>
      <br/>DDD HQ, Street
      <br/>22 Dec 2015</p>
    <p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; ">New EW Training (NET)</span></strong>
      <br/>Street HQ, City
      <br/>08 Jan 2016
      <br/>2pm - 6pm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd really like your answer. Thanks a lot. I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure **CSS** like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/251/

```
.banner-up-comming-event{
    height:40px; 
    padding-top:8px; 
    color:#fff; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color:#000; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}

.banner-up-comming-event:before {
    border-left: 15px solid #636363;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    bottom: -16px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.banner-up-comming-event:after {
    border-left: 15px solid #636363;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    bottom: -16px;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the width for `.content-up-comming-event` not resize properly. This happen when I resize the browser.

Comment: @Imran explain what do you mean.

Comment: If you resize the browser, the content of class `..content-up-comming-event` not resize properly. It does not fit with the left and right icon

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution. But this is not the best.

```css
.content-up-comming-event
{
    position:relative;
    font-size:0.85em;
    min-height:200px; 
    width:92%;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    padding:20px 15px;
    z-index:100;
}
.img-left-curve
{
    width:4%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left:-4%;
}
.img-right-curve
{
    width:4%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right:-4%;
}
.banner-up-comming-event
{
  height:40px; 
  padding-top:8px; 
  color:#fff; 
  text-align: center; 
  background-color:#000; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="banner-up-comming-event">Upcoming Event</div>
  <div class="content-up-comming-event">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ylry.png" class="img-left-curve" />
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQFpL.png" class="img-right-curve" />
    <p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; ">Events</span></strong><br/>DDD HQ, Street <br/> 22 Dec 2015</p>
    <p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline; ">New EW Training (NET)</span></strong><br/>Street HQ, City <br/> 08 Jan 2016<br/>2pm - 6pm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```